# reactjs is giving me a invariant Violation error for changing a parent's state with a callback

Tags: reactjs

The following code will result in an uncaught error:
`Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within`render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state.`

```
      var NavHabit = React.createClass(
    {
      getInitialState: function(){
        return{
          pageNum: 1
        }
      },

      handleUserClick: function(pageNum){
        this.setState({
          pageNum: this.state.pageNum + pageNum
        });
      },

      render: function(){
        return (
          <div>
          <PageNav onUserClick={this.handleUserClick} />
          <h1>Page: {this.state.pageNum} </h1>
          </div>
        )
      }
    });

  var PageNav = React.createClass({
    handleClicks: function(page){
      this.props.onUserClick(page);
    },

    render: function(){
      return(
        <div id = "page_nav">
            <ul class="pagination text-right" role="navigation" aria-label="Pagination">
                <li class="pagination-previous disabled" onClick={this.handleClicks(-1)} >Previous</li>
                <li class="pagination-next" onClick={this.handleClicks(1)} ><a href="#">Next</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
      );
    }
  });
```

I followed this example: http://codepen.io/kenwheeler/pen/kxrDu
However Im using a callback function and changing a parent's state from a child. How do I fix this problem of mine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem exists within your PageNav class. Your render function is actually executing `this.handleClicks` rather than binding it to be called later. By including the parenthesis after the function, it executes it.

You can achieve your desired result in one of two ways. Binding the function's parameter or wrapping it in another function.

```
// Option 1: Bind the function's first parameter
render: function(){
  return(
    <div id = "page_nav">
        <ul class="pagination text-right" role="navigation" aria-label="Pagination">
            <li class="pagination-previous disabled" onClick={this.handleClicks.bind(this, -1)} >Previous</li>
            <li class="pagination-next" onClick={this.handleClicks.bind(this, 1)} ><a href="#">Next</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  );
}


// Option 2: Wrapping in another function 
// (can be on React class or just inline in the render. 
// Putting it inline like this means it gets created each time render is called 
// so I recommend putting it on the React class
render: function(){
  var minus = function() {
       this.handleClicks(-1);
  };
  var plus = function() {
       this.handleClicks(1);
  };

  return(
    <div id = "page_nav">
        <ul class="pagination text-right" role="navigation" aria-label="Pagination">
            <li class="pagination-previous disabled" onClick={minus} >Previous</li>
            <li class="pagination-next" onClick={plus} ><a href="#">Next</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```